# GCC linker cannot find crt0.o, -lc, -lgloss

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I am using custom-built GCC 8.3.0 and when trying to build I get the following errors:

```
cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
cannot find -lc
cannot find -lgloss
```

What is `crt0.o`, and are `-lc` and `-lgloss` libraries? Where can I download them from?

Comment: It appears that you have not installed the compiler correctly.  `crt0.o` is an object file provided by 'the system' (the C compiler) that contains the code that calls `main()`.  `-lc` is the standard C library — kinda fundamental to linking C programs.  `-lgloss` is a library, probably `libgloss.so` or perhaps `libgloss.a`. It isn't available either. You should probably list `-lc` after `-lgloss`, though it may not matter if you're using shared libraries (which you probably are). What exactly was your command line when linking? Often you'd get a message about "cannot find libc.so", not `-lc`.

Comment: More to the point, either your "custom GCC" toolchain is lacking crt0.o (and perhaps other critical pieces), and/or your build environment isn't correctly configured to pick them up.  We need more details about this "custom GCC" in order to help you.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add more details about your "custom-built GCC 8.3.0". Where did you get it from? Did you build it yourself? Did you follow the build/installation instructions? Provide links to the source site and/or the instructions you followed.

Comment: Also, show us your Makefile and/or the command you're using to link your `.o` files together. If you used `ld` for the linker (e.g. `ld -o myprogram obj1.o obj2.o`), you might have better luck with `gcc`. For example, with `gcc` there would be no need to use `-lc` because that is automatic.